# How to solve: AttributeError: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'invite' Discord.py?

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py, attributes

I am generating invite codes to my discord guild channel through API/Integromat.

```
"uses": 0,
"max_uses": 2,
"max_age": 604800,
"unique": true
```

Nextly I want to know which invite was used to pair it with email adress for whom I sent this. For this problem I used this code:

```
#base on medium article:
#https://medium.com/@tonite/finding-the-invite-code-a-user-used-to-join-your-discord-server-using-discord-py-5e3734b8f21f

import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from keep_alive import keep_alive

intents = discord.Intents.default().all()
intents.members = True
intents.invites = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
invites = {}

@client.event
async def on_ready(): 
    for guild in client.guilds:
        invites[guild.id] = await guild.invites()

def find_invite_by_code(invite_list, code):
    for inv in invite_list:      
        if inv.code == code:
          return inv

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  
    invites_before_join = invites[member.guild.id]
    invites_after_join = await member.guild.invites()

    for invite in invites_before_join:
        if invite.uses < find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses:
            await requests.post(f"https://WEBHOOK_URL?invite={invite.code}")
            invites[member.guild.id] = invites_after_join
            return

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    invites[member.guild.id] = await member.guild.invites()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!Hey'):
      await client.wait_until_ready()
      await message.channel.send(message.id)
      return

keep_alive()
client.run(os.environ['BOT_TOKEN'])
```

When I am trying to test invite through private tab, in a console I have output:

**AttributeError: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'code'**

sometimes it's also **AttributeError: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'invite'**

Do you know where I am making a mistake??
Maybe this article give you some inspire: https://github.com/GregTCLTK/Discord-Invite-Tracker

Comment: Thanks @HampusLarsson. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

Updated 2 changes:

```
def find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, code):
        for invite in invites_after_join:      
            if invite.code == code:
              return invite
    
    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
    
        invites_before_join = invites[member.guild.id]
        invites_after_join = await member.guild.invites()
    
        for invite in invites_before_join:
            if invite.uses < find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses:
                await requests.post(f"hook?invite={invite.code}")
                invites[member.guild.id] = invites_after_join
                return
```

It's interesting because sometimes my webhook was send on the other hand not. I will update backlog here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Created invites will show only after restart bot.
So you I needed to create 100+ invites, and then manipulate.